# Spring Boot run data.sql without running schema.sql

Tags: database, spring-boot

I'm trying to run initialization script (data.sql) without running DDL (schema.sql).

Application simply can't execute DDL because of some security guidelines, so tables have to exist beforehand and this is not part of this question.

My results:

1. If both schema.sql and data.sql are present, both will execute.
2. If only schema.sql is present, it will execute.
3. If only data.sql is present, it won't execute.

I understand that executing data.sql only is probably not usual, but the only workaround for me is to create schema.sql like this (MS SQL):

```
SELECT 'true' AS 'whatever';
```

so that the script is not null or empty and data.sql is then executed as intended.

I am using spring boot version 1.5.16.RELEASE

application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    jndi-name: java:/datasource/mssql
    initialization-mode: always
  jpa:
    properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
```

Is there any better option?

Comment: I'm using this approach for testing in combination with flyway but with Spring Boot 2. Have you spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always set?

Comment: Yes and I've added application.yml to the question.

Comment: as i said this works for me. Do you have any code that i can run?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the actual code, but i will try to make minimalistic project in my spare time to demonstrate this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to defer data.sql until hibernate creates table. Hopefully adding this to your application.yml will solve the problem

```
spring:
```

jpa:
defer-datasource-initialization: true